# Can I influence the return type of a CDI producer?

Tags: java, cdi

I am using CDI to inject a Hessian Server Connection which enables me to create different service Proxies.

Simple example:

```
@Inject HessianServer server;

NameService service;

@PostConstruct
private void init{
    service  = server.getProxy(NameService.class);
}
```

This works fine. But I have to initiate many of those Services. Therefore I'd rather like to just inject the service.

I built myself a ServiceProducer Class that creates the service depending on a parameterized CDI qualifier:

```
@Inject HessianServer server;

@Produces
@Service(serviceType = ServiceType.NAME)
NameService produce(){
    return server.getProxy(NameService.class);
}
```

Now I can inject the service:

```
@Inject
@Service(serviceType = ServiceType.NAME)
NameService nameService;
```

But I need such a produce Method for any kind of Service I want to produce.

I would like to improve the Producer Class to generate the fitting Service Implementation based on the Qualifier Parameter. Then I'd only need one produce method instead of one for each Service I want to produce.
Therefore, instead of passing an enum value in the CDI Qualifier, I pass the classType.
For example something like this.

```
@Produces
@Service(serviceType = NameService.class)
_whatMustIReturnHere_ produce(InjectionPoint ip){
    Service service = injectionPoint.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(Service.class);
    return server.getProxy(service.getServiceType); 
}
```

The question is: Is it even possible to influence the return type of the produce method based on the passed qualifier parameter? If so, how?

Comment: You will at least need a common interface or supertype for all your implementations.

Comment: Hm. This is not possible, because I can not influence the interfaces and their implementations. So I guess the answer is is simply: No, it is not possible.

Comment: Yes. It's how cdi works.   The container needs to inject an instance and looks for a producer.  So you will need a producer that returns that type.

Answer (score 0):

While the default bean types of a producer method is the closure of the return type as specified in [Bean types of a producer method](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#producer_method_types), it is possible to override the set of types with the [Portable extensions](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#spi) mechanism.

To meet your need, you can create a CDI extension that observes for the [`ProcessBeanAttributes`](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#process_bean_attributes) event, and overriding the corresponding `BeanAttributes` information, e.g.:

```
class ServiceExtension implements Extension {

    void overrideBean(@Observes final ProcessBeanAttributes<NameService> pba) {
        pba.setBeanAttributes(new BeanAttributes<NameService>() {

            public Set<Type> getTypes() {
                Set<Type> types = new HashSet<>(pba.getBeanAttributes().getTypes());
                types.add(_whatMustIReturnHere_);
                return types;
            }

            public Set<Annotation> getQualifiers() {
                return pba.getBeanAttributes().getQualifiers();
            }

            public Class<? extends Annotation> getScope() {
                return pba.getBeanAttributes().getScope();
            }

            public String getName() {
                return pba.getBeanAttributes().getName();
            }

            public Set<Class<? extends Annotation>> getStereotypes() {
                return pba.getBeanAttributes().getStereotypes();
            }

            public boolean isAlternative() {
                return pba.getBeanAttributes().isAlternative();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The advantage of that approach is that it still relies on the [Typesafe resolution](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#typesafe_resolution) mechanism so you'll get the standard exceptions thrown during deployment of your application should there be an ambiguous or unsatisfied dependency.